# Sonar Code Coverage reduces after JacocoMerge

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco

I am trying to generate sonar report for my multi-module java project. But after doing jacocoMerge I see the coverage reduces drastically. See the below screenshots:

Code coverage with Unit and Integration Separate:
[image: Code coverage with Unit and Integration Separate]
Code coverage After JacocoMerge:
[image: Code coverage After JacocoMerge]
I used below code to merge the coverage:

```
task jacocoMergeAll(type: JacocoMerge) {
    dependsOn(subprojects.test)
    subprojects.each { subproject ->
        def testTask = subproject.tasks.withType(Test)
        if(new File("$subproject.buildDir/jacoco/test.exec").exists()){
            executionData(testTask)
        }
    }
}
```

I am using sonarQube version 5.6.3 and jacoco plugin version is 0.7.7.201606060606.

Why does the coverage drop after jacocoMerge? Please help.